# Sprites on top of each other and Events?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a sprite, inside this sprite is 2 sprites, sprite A and sprite B.

sprite A is on top of sprite B, the click event listener for sprite A fires but for Sprite B it doesnt.

How can I get bot to fire?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to repropagate the event to the Sprites manually.  See: [Click to underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715897/click-to-hit-underneath/7718275#7718275)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Event Listener to the `parent` container of `Sprite A` and `Sprite B`, for example:

```
parent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event : MouseEvent) : void { 
    trace("User clicked on: " event.target);

    if (event.target == spriteA) {
        // Do something...
    }
});
```

You can then add some conditional logic to your event handler function.